# Running Newman command with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, postman, newman

I have a Newman command that is part of my script. I'd like the entire script to quit (or go back to the main menu) when the collection encounters an error.

```
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE
from io import TextIOWrapper

def run_sh(command):
    process = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=PIPE)
    for line in TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, newline=""):
        print(line, "")

cmd = newman run "My_Collection.postman_collection.json" --folder "My_Folder" -e ../../Postman/Environments/My_Environment.json -d "CREDS.txt" -r cli,csv -n 1 --reporter-csv-includeBody --reporter-csv-export ./RESPONSES.csv
```

The `run_sh(cmd)` is part of a bigger script. I'd like the script to not carry on to the next step if errors are encountered when running the collection. Using `try` and `except` won't work because the `run_sh` command successfully goes through (it runs the collection but the collection yields errors).

Example of an error:

```
  #  failure         detail                                                
 
                                                                           
 
 1.  AssertionError  Status code is 202                                    
 
                     expected response to have status code 202 but got 401 
 
                     at assertion:0 in test-script                         
 
                     inside "MY FOLDER"
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: `cmd = newman run "My_Collection.postman_collection.json" --folder "My_Folder" -e ../../Postman/Environments/My_Environment.json -d "CREDS.txt" -r cli,csv -n 1 --reporter-csv-includeBody --reporter-csv-export ./RESPONSES.csv
` doesn't look like Python syntax. What's going on here?

Comment: Anyhow -- first question: Does the command you're running correctly report its exit status? Use `check=True` with `subprocess.run()` to cause an exception if a program being run has a nonzero exit status, or call `.wait()` and check its `returncode` yourself.

Comment: Check for the token in  your request because 401 means unauthorized. your request might require authorization code/token